# PHP handling multiple clauses in an IF statement

Tags: php, if-statement, boolean

I have a php code that does this:

```
if (file_get_contents($businessData['header_image'],0,null,0,1) !== false) {
    $headerBackingImage = $businessData['header_image'];
    }
else {
    $headerBackingImage = "default_image_url.jpg";
}
```

The purpose is to establish if the business has a valid image file at the defined location, to then use that file URL in the webpage. The `$businessData` is an array of outputs from a database.

what I am finding is that with some database rows the `$businessData['header_image']` value is empty, and this is causing warnings:

> PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty

So obviously, the precursor to the above statement is to check that `$businessData['header_image']` is not empty. Easily done with PHP `empty()` function.

I *could* structure it as the following:

```
if (!empty($var)){
    if (file_get_contents($var)){
    ///file exists!
    }
else {
    ///file does not exist, use default.
    }
}
else {
        ///file does not exist, use default.
        }
```

But this would mean repeating the `else` clause inside and outside of the IF EMPTY check.

### My question

So - How about this layout to maintain a single `IF{...}` statement and not need to repeat the `ELSE{...}` clause :

```
if (!empty($businessData['header_image']) && file_get_contents($businessData['header_image'],0,null,0,1) !== false){ ... }
```

So, *Does PHP bother checking the second condition in the IF statement if the first condition returns FALSE?*

Would the above solution still return a WARNING, because PHP still runs the `file_get_contents` function even after evaluating the first --`empty()`-- function as FALSE?

The stuff I've read about this from php.net and other places seems to only evaluate IF conditionals as single return blocks, as in the whole block between the brackets returns TRUE or FALSE rather than how PHP handles each sub part of the IF condition returning TRUE or FALSE individually.

Comment: Test it, and you'll find out. :)

Comment: @ClémentMalet that is very true, but I think it's also an interesting question of IF statement dynamics, and some searching on the interwebs found little that told me the answer in principle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, Does PHP bother checking the second condition in the IF statement if the first condition returns FALSE?

No here if the first part of the AND statement is flase PHP doesn't care about the second part. You can easily see this here:

```
<?php

    function func() { echo "HERE!";}

    if(false && func()) {
        echo "yes";
    } else {
        echo "no";
    }

?>
```

output:

```
no
```

So as you can see you didn't get the output: `HERE!`. But if you change the false to true you will get: `HERE!no`, because the function got called, because the first part is true.

**EDIT:**

If you want to take it exactly this is called: **short circuit evaluation**

You can see this in the manual here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

And a quote from there:

> // **foo()** will **never get called** as those operators are **short-circuit**

```
$a = (false && foo());
$b = (true  || foo());
$c = (false and foo());
$d = (true  or  foo());
```

Well this behaviour is probable, because PHP is based on C. And in C you have short circuiting which can be very useful there.

Comment: Thanks for the example, Rizier. this is the answer I hoped to get.  So I expect that my `empty()` clause will cause the error log to stop stating the WARNINGS because `file_gets_contents` will only run if the string is not empty.

Comment: @Martin yes!, you can also test it and see it for yourself :D

Comment: @Rizier123 Don't be lazy. Adding a line saying "This is called 'Short-circuit Evaluation' and is communly used in many languages to speed up the evaluation process." is enough to make your answer complete

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I don't really see your logic - your link to wikipedia is not specific to PHP (which has various [non boolean] operators that do not act quite as would be expected in other languages) . Rizier's answer told me exactly what I needed to know :)

Comment: @Martin I don't get it... Yes, it isn't specific to PHP, but PHP isn't the only language in the world, let alone the only one using this. Javascript, SQL and C are 3 languages that use Short-Circuit Evaluation.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel updated my answer, now satisfied? Even with a php official source

Comment: @Rizier123 That's way better than expected. I would just add the Wikipedia link, but other than that I'm very pleased with the edit and upvoted now

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I think my question is not aimed at the operators, I think I know what the operators do,but it's the knowledge specifically as to how the IF statement interprets the arguments themselves that I was curious about. Cheers for your help, though. Maybe I'm confused, but I was wanting to check the method behind the logic of how the IF statement reaches a boolean conclusion rather than the IF operators. :-/

Comment: @Martin I think you are really confused. `$a && foo()` if the same as `if($a){ foo(); }` and `if($a && foo()){}`. `if`'s are language constructors and not functions. PHP interprets the logical operators, independently if it is in an `if` or not. If the operators were tied to the `if`, then you couldn't do `$a = $b && foo();`.

Comment: Ahhh, I see I have been a bit confused, cheers for the clarification, that last comment is useful in showing the logical steps behind an IF a bit more .  it looks like a multi-clause IF is a shorthand way of writing many IF statements each of which is checked left-to-right,... is that correct ?

Comment: @Martin No, that isn't entirely correct. Sadly, I'm not skilled in explaining myself. I would view it as chained conditions to meet a final value. Consider the sentence: `If the signal is green, I will cross the road and I will stop in the middle if it turns red again.` This can be translated into this pseudocode: `if( is_green() && walk_half_way() ){ if( is_red() ){ wait(); } walk_half_way(); }`. This can be written as: `is_green() && walk_half_way() && ( (is_red() && wait()) || true ) && walk_half_way();` Basically it is a set of conditions you have to meet for an end. (continue)

Comment: @Martin A better example would be a recepie to make a delicious omellet. You need things like gas, stove, fire, frying pan, oil, eggs, flour (some crazy people do this), ferment (to make it grow, not necessary) and filling. You can try to make an omellet without eggs, but it will be just something that isn't omellet. You can try to make it without filling, but that will be scrambled eggs. An `if` is just like that: a set of conditions to take a decision on what to do. Another example is that you will run if isn't raining and isn't cold. If one fails, you won't run. (continue...)

Comment: @Martin `If`'s are called `control structures` since they control the flow of the code based on * conditions* . I know I'm talking a lot, but if you Google for 'php if', you will find it talking about control structures. Short-circuit evaluation is a way to get faster to the end result when the result is known without the need to check all the parameters. You won't start cooking your omellet if you don't have a frying pan, right? You check everything else and verify you are missing a condition. You know you can't do omellet. You will eat pizza again, if you have a hoven.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel thanks for the info. I have from this tried to Google various combos of IF control structure but none of what I've found explains what you're explaining -- what I'm asking in the Q. Do you have a link to further details? many thanks for the already given info.

Comment: @Martin No, I don't have a link to support it. I only have my understanding and the technical names and information. But I know you are trying to understand something beyound that (at least, that is what i feel). Can you try to make a concrete answer? I will answer anything you ask.

Answer (score 0):

Conditions are parsed from left to right and not executed if not necessary like in your suggested code. The thing to understand is that if the first part is false the entire block is false, thus it's the entire block returning false as well.

Comment: This answer is incomplete.